# Escape backslashes in Doctrine Migrations

Tags: doctrine-orm, mysql-8.0, symfony5, php-7.4, doctrine-migrations

I have a table called Entity. It has a field with the namespace of an entity like this:

`Old\App\Email` which I'm trying to rename to `New\App\Email`.

I got this **working SQL query** to rename all rows in the **MySQL** Console. It needs 4 `\` in the condition and 2 `\` in `REPLACE`:

`UPDATE Entity SET entity_name = REPLACE(entity_name, 'Old\\App', 'New\\App') WHERE entity_name LIKE 'Old\\\\App%';`

It was already hard to get it working correctly escaped, but now when trying to add it to a **Doctrine Migration**.

`$this->addSql('update log set entity_name = replace(entity_name, \'Old\', \'New\') where entity_name like \'Old\App%\'');`

It's executed without making changes. I assume it is not escaping properly.
I have trying all combination of escaping from on to 4 backslashes. And even tried the different combination of **quote escaping** hoping that this would yield the expected escaping but **no row is being changed at all**:

```
$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, \'Old\', \'New1\') where entity_name like \'Old\App%\'');
$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, \'Old\', \'New2\') where entity_name like \'Old\\App%\'');
$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, \'Old\', \'New3\') where entity_name like \'Old\\\App%\'');
$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, \'Old\', \'New4\') where entity_name like \'Old\\\\App%\'');

$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, "Old", "New5") where entity_name like "Old\App%"');
$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, "Old", "New6") where entity_name like "Old\\App%"');
$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, "Old", "New7") where entity_name like "Old\\\App%"');
$this->addSql('update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, "Old", "New8") where entity_name like "Old\\\\App%"');
```

Any help from fellow programmers would be appreciated.

Doctrine version is 2.7

Comment: You can look at here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.quote

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but it takes 7 or 8 `\` in the where clause and 4 in the replace function outside wrapped in double quotes and  the search strings with single quotes:

`$this->addSql("update Entity set entity_name = replace(entity_name, 'Old\\\\App', 'New\\\\App') where entity_name like 'Old\\\\\\\\App%'");`